# Why isn't Rails with nginx and a self-signed SSL certificate working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, self-signed

I'm trying to test my SSL setup before migrating over a site from Heroku to a (Digital Ocean) VPS, so I'm using a self-signed certificate as per [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04).

I used the following command to create the certificates, and they are present in the appropriate directory:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt
```

Here are the relevant lines from the `server` block on my nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name migration.my_domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
```

Additionally, in `production.rb` I've used the following line:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

`my_domain` (not the actual domain name) and its subdomain `migration` are both set up in my DNS and are correctly pointing to my server's IP address. At present, when I access via `http://migration.my_domain.com` pages get served up. But when I access via `https://migration.my_domain.com`, I'm getting an error in Chrome:

```
This site can’t be reached

migration.my_domain.com refused to connect.
Try:
Reloading the page
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: firewall rules?   is the server listening `netstat -an ` or  `ss -a` depending upon version of linux.

Comment: Firewall is in the default state accepting all input, output and forwards. I assume it's listening in general since regular http requests are being handled appropriately.

Comment: run the command to make sure it is listening on port 443. are you running a proxy?

Comment: I don't see it listening on port 443. I'm new to this so I don't know if I'm running a proxy, but I doubt it since I'm setting this up more or less by the Digital Ocean recipe and I haven't seen anything about that. How do I get the server to listen on port 443? Shouldn't the `listen 443` line do that?

Comment: try putting the ssl into another server block with the same config as the port 80 one save for the ssl lines,  and then restart ngninx (you are restarting nginx/ droplet between changes to the file correct..)

Comment: Your most recent comment contains part of the solution to my problem (thanks!). I was deploying using capistrano which I had assumed was restarting nginx after a deploy (it does restart all other rails-related processes). Turns out it didn't. So I need to do that manually after each deploy if there's a change in nginx.conf. So that was step one in my solution. I'm updating now to include the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. First, I'm deploying via Capistrano which I had mistakenly thought was restarting nginx after a deploy. Turns out it doesn't. So I needed to do that manually. So deployed with this at the beginning of my `server` block:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server deferred;
  server_name migration.my_domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
```

Deployed that, but after restarting nginx, first got the warning from Chrome about a self-signed certificate and that the site can't be trusted (which is fine and expected). After moving past that got a message about too many redirects. Turns out that the line from above in my `production.rb` file:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

was causing a problem. Saw [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/error-too-many-redirect-on-nginx) which from what I can tell means that what nginx sends through to puma does not contain whether it's ssl or not, so puma redirects *everything*, even the https requests because it just doesn't know what it's getting. So, now I have two near-duplicate `server` blocks. The first one which handles `http` requests has the following relevant statements:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name migration.my_domain.com;

  # ...bunch of non-relevant config...

  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
}
```

This handles all the 80 requests which puma will redirect all of to ssl (I believe) thanks to `config.force_ssl = true` in `production.rb`. Nginx will then receive an https request for the same URL which will be handled by this block:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name migration.my_domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

  # ...bunch of non-relevant config...

  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; # IMPORTANT!! I believe this tells puma that everything sent through via this block is https. Thus, puma no longer redirects.
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
}
```

This seems to work correctly, albeit with all the appropriate warnings one should get in the browser when receiving a self-signed certificate. I'm confident that once I switch in my actual certificates, I will now have a functioning ssl setup.

Thanks again @doon!

Comment: This worked for me with a Sharetribe behind a NGINX SSL Proxy.

--> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; # IMPORTANT!! I believe this tells puma that everything sent through via this block is https. Thus, puma no longer redirects.
    
Thank You!